# Merge java source files into one

Tags: java, regex

I have a main java file (let's call it `MainDynamic.java`) and it uses a couple of other classes (in their own source files).

For reasons that may seem weird to you I want to create a file (let's call this one `MainStatic.java`) that is basically a version of `MainDynamic.java` where all used classes are pasted into, so that it becomes one huge (unreadable almost) file that is "self contained" and only imports classes from the standard library.

All the necessary imports from the included classes will have to be imported in the static file or the source code has to be (automatically) modified to use absolute identifiers.

I tried some regex magic but that seems to have limits as to what it can do with imports etc. Googling didn't directly spawn a magical piece of code either.

So: What's the easiest way to do this? Did somebody do this before me (and if can you point me to the code/implementation)? (I want to avoid to spend too much time with approaches that are doomed to fail eventually)

---

Edit: **Why?** I'll be participating in a competition and they only allow single-file submissions. (Don't ask me why). I find it very (very) annoying to work in a huge file with tons of classes inside (to do some backtracking, constrained searching in graphs etc. you need some classes). Manually patching everything together is too time consuming.

Comment: *Did somebody do this before me*: I doubt it. This sounds like a really really bad idea. Why would you do that?

Comment: Are the files you're merging together already importing each other? Do you have an existing package structure? If so, can you ensure that each unqualified class name (that is, class name without its package name) is unique?

Comment: Can you enlighten us to the reason why you are doing this?  If you are trying to make it easier to compile... well there are lots of tools out there (e.g., Ant, Eclipse) that make it easy to build Java projects with lots of files.  If you are trying to store the source code somewhere like a database, why not zip all the files up instead?

Comment: I edited the question to explain why ;)

Comment: @David They could be importing each other, they could theoretically have the same name, but I could account for that, so you can assume they have distinct names

Comment: @JBNizet If I could avoid it I would, but right now my options are: working in different files and putting them together (automatically) vs. working in one single file with tons of classes inside

Comment: You could submit a single zip file containing all the classes ;-)

Comment: @JBNizet Unfortunately not! Has to be a file called Main.java that can be compiled and executed automatically. They really do not like java programmers I think!

Comment: You might just want to write a Java program/script that does this.  You can keep it simple by making some constraints and rules on how you write the files.  For example, always put `import` at the very top together, make sure all .java files are in the same directory, etc.  Then it's just a matter of parsing the `imports` and getting a distinct list, then dumping all the files together into a single file.

Comment: @mellamokb you're probably right, that's the approach I tend towards now!

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing, but for different reasons (ease of deployment into an Oracle server-side JVM, of sources not classes/jars). Did anymore come up with a good solution for this? Basically one needs to use the AST of all sources, and intelligently merge them into a new AST, and reserialize that new one.

Answer (score 2):

Approach suggested by [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb):

> You might just want to write a Java program/script that does this. You can keep it simple by making some constraints and rules on how you write the files. For example, always put import at the very top together, make sure all .java files are in the same directory, etc. Then it's just a matter of parsing the imports and getting a distinct list, then dumping all the files together into a single file.

Comment: This should be a [Community Wiki Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/206345).